# How to use gestures with scrollview - Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using onFling in my views to get a swipe to next activity. However this does not work if the view has a scrollview surrounding it.

Apparently it absorbs the gestures and stops my onFling.

Is there anyway around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this piece of code: (Override `ScrollView`'s dispatchTouchEvent)

```
public class yourScrollView extends ScrollView{

    //constructors and everything
    //You might want to pass your GestureDetector (of course)

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);    
        return myGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I just put it in the same activity? I think I tried this but it did not seem to work.

Comment: no you should create a `class yourScrollView extends ScrollView` and this code in it

Comment: - then I use that class instead of the ScrollView in the xml layout?

Comment: any hints as to what is the best way to pass the `GestureDector`?

Answer (score 4):

You are right, ScrollView "steals" the gesture because of it's inherit functionality. I've worked around this before by applying the onTouchListener to the ScrollView itself instead of its immediate parent view.

Comment: how do I do this? do I find the ScrollView threw id and hook it up?

Comment: Yes, grab the ScrollView object and use the setOnTouchListener()

Comment: after searching for a while, this was the best solution i found to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment answers so I write a new one.
I found that overriding the `dispatchTouchEvent` of `ScrollView` works well but the gesture handler needs to be called **before** the `super.dispatchTouchEvent` as that method could change the event coordinates in some weird way. In particular I have seen the Y value jumping when trying to vertically scroll past the end of the view.
Calling the gesture handler before the scroll view handling will let it use the scroll view coordinates and not the internal scrolled ones.

So:

```
public class yourScrollView extends ScrollView{

    //constructors and everything

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        return myGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev) | super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev); 
    }
}
```

Elements in the scroll view react as long as the view does not start scrolling, but the gestures are correctly detected.