# How to detect onFling of widget on ScrollView?

Tags: android

I have many ImageView on ScrollView (which scrolls vertical).
And I want to detect vertically onFling of ImageView.
I tried to implement SimpleGestureDetector to ImageView then I can detect onFling 
when I flicking horizontally. But when I flicking vertically then I can't detect.
How cant I detect vertically onFling?

I found some solution about problem resembles mine:

[How to use gestures with scrollview - Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949713/how-to-use-gestures-with-scrollview-android)

If I have only one ImageView on my ScrollView then this solution maybe works, But I have multiple ImageViews on ScrollView that generated dynamically. 
So maybe this solution will not work for me...